# Reading from a file line by line and word by word in C

Tags: c, file

I have to read from a file and store the data in a structure.(You can see the structure below) Each line consists of 5 integers and 1 char variable. Each line must be an index of the "structure line".

```
struct line {
    int lineno;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    char color;
    int next;
};

struct line memorybuffer[25];
```

For example in this file:

```
1 10 10 50 60 R
3 80 10 10 10 B
4 40 20 40 0 Y
```

I should get:

```
memorybuffer[0].lineno = 1;
memorybuffer[0].x1 = 10;
memorybuffer[1].lineno = 3;
```

I could not find how can I read the data (integer+char) line by line and word by word, and store it in the line structure.

Could you please help me to find the way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read a line with `fgets()`. Use `sscanf()` to try to parse that string and populate an instance of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not find how can I read the data

Please read the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) for `fscanf`, which can address your needs *completely*.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by *Shawn* you can read the file one line at a time with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct line {
    int lineno;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    char color;
    int next;
};

struct line memorybuffer[25];

int main() {
    char line[256];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 25 && fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);) {
        if (sscanf("%d %d %d %d %d %c\n",
                   &memorybuffer[i].lineno,
                   &memorybuffer[i].x1,
                   &memorybuffer[i].y1,
                   &memorybuffer[i].x2,
                   &memorybuffer[i].y2,
                   &memorybuffer[i].color) == 6) {
            /* record was parsed correctly */
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("invalid format: %s", line);
        }
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```